# Spring Boot 2.0.5 upgrade to 2.1.1 fail on start Jcache issue

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-boot-actuator

Got error on SpringBoot start. With old version works as expected. I'm suspecting issue related to new actuator metrics (/actuator/caches) which has been added in 2.1.x version. How to solve this?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperConfigurer' defined in class path resource [springfox/documentation/spring/web/SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalJCacheAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/jcache/config/ProxyJCacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.BeanFactoryJCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jCacheOperationSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/jcache/config/ProxyJCacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheOperationSource]: Factory method 'cacheOperationSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: cacheManager
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding in gradle
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-cache
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'